# SQL - how to display products' options, whether or not they have them?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table, entity-attribute-value

Assume a `products` can have 0 or more `options` -- implemented with the following tables:

```
products
 - id
 - name

options
 - id
 - name

product_options
 - id
 - product_id
 - option_id
```

Further assume the following products have the following options:

- Product 1 = Option 1, Option 2, Option 3
- Product 2 = Option 2, Option 3, Option 4
- Product 3 = Option 3, Option 4, Option 5

**How can I query this so that I get results like this:**

- Product 1, Option 1, Option 2, Option 3, NULL, NULL
- Product 2, NULL, Option 2, Option 3, Option 4, NULL
- Product 3, NULL, NULL, Option 3, Option 4, Option 5

My options are actually a nested tree. And they have a foreign key to a categories table (also a nested tree). Ultimately, I need to be able to do this query and group the results by category. However, I probably should understand first how to solve this simpler version of my problem.

**UPDATE 1:** I do not know in advance what the options might be. Also, there is no limit to the number of options a product may have.

Comment: how many distinct options are possible?

Comment: ...Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala - unlimited.

Comment: Recommendation: Get rid of the options table by not normalizing them.  You are using the EAV schema, which does not scale well; by normalizing `option_names` you are making it worse.

Comment: These options are meant to increase/decrease over time. How do I not use EAV? Each option should become a column in the `products` table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an unknown number of options you could use a stored procedure to dynamically create a query that can be used to pivot your table. Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE display_options()
BEGIN
  SET @query = 'SELECT p.id, ';
  SET @query = CONCAT(@query, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN o.name = ''', name, ''' THEN o.name END) AS `', name, '`')) FROM options ORDER BY id));
  SET @query = CONCAT_WS(' ', @query, 
                         'FROM products p',
                         'JOIN product_options po ON po.product_id = p.id',
                         'JOIN options o ON o.id = po.option_id',
                         'GROUP BY p.id');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

This procedure will produce a query like this (essentially the same as in @GordonLinoff's answer for the sample data in your question):

```
SELECT p.name, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN o.name = 'Option 1' THEN o.name END) AS `Option 1`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN o.name = 'Option 2' THEN o.name END) AS `Option 2`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN o.name = 'Option 3' THEN o.name END) AS `Option 3`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN o.name = 'Option 4' THEN o.name END) AS `Option 4`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN o.name = 'Option 5' THEN o.name END) AS `Option 5` 
FROM products p 
JOIN product_options po ON po.product_id = p.id 
JOIN options o ON o.id = po.option_id 
GROUP BY p.name
```

which can then be prepared and executed to give results like this:

```
name        Option 1    Option 2    Option 3    Option 4    Option 5
Product 1   Option 1    Option 2    Option 3        
Product 2               Option 2    Option 3    Option 4    
Product 3                           Option 3    Option 4    Option 5
```

[demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=38144a3d5477cc7c06f58d9ca3acd220)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without a stored procedure?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie I don't believe so because of the variable number of columns. I'll be watching for other answers though - perhaps someone will prove me wrong.

Answer (score 3):

After so many of trials I found below query that will return exact result as you want even if options and product may increases.

```
SELECT  CONCAT(P.productName, ",", GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(IF(P.optionId IN (product_options.option_id),P.optionName,NULL),"NULL") order by P.optionId)) AS result
FROM product_options
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT products.id as productId,  products.name as productName,options.id as optionId, options.name AS optionName from products,options) 
as P On P.productId = product_options.product_id AND P.optionId = product_options.option_id
GROUP BY P.productId
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dfdccc3664b6231c67acac17d0f5610a

Comment: Got it ! You are testing it on MySql 8, which is case sensitive for identifiers. In my query earlier I missed case sensitivity. I have updated my answer please check

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation, if I understand correctly:

```
select po.product_id,
       max(case when o.name = 'Option 1' then o.name end) as option_1,
       max(case when o.name = 'Option 2' then o.name end) as option_2,
       max(case when o.name = 'Option 3' then o.name end) as option_3,
       max(case when o.name = 'Option 4' then o.name end) as option_4,
       max(case when o.name = 'Option 5' then o.name end) as option_5
from product_options po join
     options o
     on po.option_id = o.id
group by po.product_id
```

Comment: This works if I have a finite list of options -- and that I know them in advance. I don't know what the possible options are.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie . . . Then you would need a dynamic pivot.  A SQL query returns a fixed set of columns.

Comment: No experience with dynamic pivots, but at least I have something to google now. I keep thinking I need to do a subquery somehow -- to get the list of options first, then try to do something like you did?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie . . . You can do that as well.

Comment: Is my idea possible? Can you please suggest how that can be done?

Comment: [_This_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav) discusses a compromise on EAV.

Answer (score 1):

**Do you really need to structure the display at the DB level?**

Honestly, if it's at all feasible, I'd save myself the headace and run:

```
  SELECT p.*, o.*
    FROM product_options po
    JOIN products p
      ON p.id = po.product_id
    JOIN options o
      ON o.id = po.option_id
   WHERE ...
ORDER BY ...
```

You can then sort out your desired structure at the application level as you iterate through the result set

Answer (score 0):

Product options are important in ecommerce, usually more complicated than above given question.
For example in any standard application say 'Opencart' we have following 6 tables for options

1. Table occw_option  - columns: option_id, type
2. Table occw_option_description -columns: option_id,  language_id, name
3. Table occw_option_value -columns: option_id, option_value_id, image
4. Table occw_option_value_description - columns: option_value_id, language_id,option_id, name
5. Table occw_product_option -colums: product_option_id, product_id, option_id, value
6. Table occw_product_option_value - columns: product_option_value_id,product_option_id, product_id, option_id, option_value_id
   quantity, price price_prefix, points, points_prefix,  weight, weight_prefix

Easiest and best thing to do is to use left joins
like for example say your 'product_id' is '59'

```
SELECT product_option_value_id,product_option_id, product_id, quantity, price, price_prefix, points, points_prefix, weight, weight_prefix, occw_option_description.name, occw_option_description.language_id, occw_option.type,occw_option_value.image, occw_option_value_description.name 
FROM `occw_product_option_value` 
left join `occw_option` on occw_product_option_value.option_id = occw_option.option_id 
left join `occw_option_description` on occw_product_option_value.option_id = occw_option_description.option_id 
left join `occw_option_value` on occw_product_option_value.option_value_id = occw_option_value.option_value_id 
left join `occw_option_value_description` on occw_option_value.option_value_id = occw_option_value_description.option_value_id 
WHERE occw_product_option_value.product_id = 59
```

You will get nicely all info you require for your front end like below

```
product_option_value_id, product_option_id, product_id, quantity,price, price_prefix, points, points_prefix, weight, weight_prefix, name, language_id, type, image, name
84  250  59 111 0.00 + 0 + 0.00 + Brand 1 radio XLL
83  250  59 122 0.00 + 0 + 0.00 + Brand 1 radio XL
82  250  59 45  0.00 + 0 + 0.00 + Brand 1 radio M
81  250  59 34  0.00 + 0 + 0.00 + Brand 1 radio L
```

These above are say for 'product' shirt sizes options XLL, XL, M, L which a customer can choose by 'radio' at the front end